# How to prevent auto scrolling when image dragged beyond viewport

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a web page with images that can be dropped on a canvas div (nothing to do with HTML5) and then dragged around. The problem is that if I drag an image far off to the right the whole page scrolls left to keep the image displayed.  I don't want this "auto scroll."  When the image gets to the right edge of the viewport, it should stop: you can't drag it any farther. I tried adding containment : 'viewport' to the image dragOps, but that didn't help.

Is there a way I can prevent this auto scrolling?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could listen for mousedown event and prevent scrolling, then listen for mouseup and allow scrolling again?

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily